# Why can't I create a bibliography in TexMaker?

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

This is my first time trying to create citations and a bibliography. I have read plenty of information online and watched numerous videos. I still am not sure if I understand it. I am using TexMaker since it is the only software that works well for me.

1. Following and online guide here is how my main document looks.

> ```
> \documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
> \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \begin{titlepage}
> \title{Homework 1: Annotated Bibliography}
> \author{Author Name}
> \end{titlepage}
> \maketitle
>
> Game Theory \cite{test}
>
> \bibliography{anbib}
> \bibliographystyle{plain}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

2. I created a file called  anbib.bib and placed in the same folder.

> @article{test,
> title={A general theory of equilibrium selection in
> games},   author={Harsanyi, John C and Selten, Reinhard},
> journal={MIT Press Books},   volume={1},   year={1988},
> publisher={The MIT Press} }

3. I try to compile the main file using quickquick build in TexMaker and the title shows up fine. Then I get in the main text Game Theory [?]. Furthermore I do not see a bibliography in my document.

What am I doing wrong? I read somewhere that I can download software called BibTex to make a bibliography document. I cannot find it for download anywhere.

Sorry about the formatting. Normally all my code shows up fine in StackExchange. For some reason not so much here.

Comment: You have to run `bibtex`. I'm not sure if TeXmaker's Quick Build does this. You can check in the Options menu.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I can select BibTex in the drop down menu. And I run it. Now if I run Quick Build again I see a references section.  However, in the main text I still see a [?].

Comment: You have to do the sequence: `latex+latex+bibtex+latex+view` or `pdflatex` if you wish a pdf output. If I'm not wrong: F6 F6 F11 (F12) F6 F7

Comment: Im not sure about the F-keys. But I did that sequence in the exact order. The reference section is there. I still have the [?] in the main text.

Comment: It works here. Are you sure that you run `bibtex` instead of  `biblatex`?

Comment: It looks like it works now. Apparently you have to run it several times. Thank you for your help. Now on too figuring out how to add an annotation to the reference.

Comment: You have to run `bibtex` only if you cite a new reference.

Comment: What do you mean by *annotation*? Maybe `\cite[Theorem~3.2]{test}`

Comment: OK. Thanks. Like I said, completely new to all of this. Just out of curiosity what does the latex command do that quick build doesn't. Also, do you have any idea of how to add an annotation into the bibliography?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25037/discussion-between-amkas90-and-sigur).

Comment: i've just looked at the texmaker documentation for "quick build". it does seem to delete some files when starting up, but it's not totally clear on which all of them are.  if it deletes the `.bbl` file, then you will get the result you describe.  so, instead of "quick build", simply run latex again, and then view the output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Nice! So why people developing TeXmaker don't fix this problem!

Comment: @Sigur -- a good question.  they could at least document what files the "quick build" deletes.  more to the point, why don't they check for the presence of a `.bib` file, and if it's there, run bibtex from the "quick build"? (not a user, so i'm not going to report it, but the op could, if this turns out to be the problem.)

Comment: I will do that. Do either of you know how to add an annotation to the bibliography. It should look like what is at the bottom of this document that I found. http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/graduate/CMSC601/Spring09/bib-guidelines.pdf

Comment: Add `note = {Annotation appended to entry in bibliography.}` to the relevant entry in your `.bib` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton with quick build you can do all this in one pass example you can run : pdflatex +bib(la)tex+pdflatex(2times)+pdfviewer.

Comment: @touhami -- is what you describe automatic, or does it have to be "set up"?  if the latter, i didn't see any obvious documentation on the texmaker site, but i wasn't looking for it either.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You have to set it up, but i really don't see the point. I want a *Quick build*, no need to run bibtex and latex several times when i want a quick look at the output. Maybe they should add a button *complete build*. Could be a feature request.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's as johannes_B said

Comment: Thats cool. Can just select it under options to change the default Quick Build path. Did not see that before.